# Rails weird default routing behaviour in nested namespace in resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this in my router.rb:

```
  namespace :me do
    namespace :bills do
      get :consumption_invoice, :format => :pdf
    end
  end
```

and also

```
  resources :groups do
    member do
      namespace :bills do
        get :consumption_invoice, :format => :pdf
      end
    end
  end
```

The first one gives me:

```
   me_bills_consumption_invoice GET    /me/bills/consumption_invoice(.:format)                        me/bills#consumption_invoice {:format=>:pdf}

consumption_invoice_bills_group GET    /groups/:id/bills/consumption_invoice(.:format)                bills/groups#consumption_invoice {:format=>:pdf}
```

In the group, the controller called is `bills/groups#consumption_invoice` instead of `groups/bills#consumption_invoice` as I'd expect.

Why?

Thanks

---

EDIT

After some reflexion, here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
/me/bills/consumption_invoice => :controller => :bills, :action => :consumption_invoice
# and
/groups/:id/bills/consumption_invoice => :controller => :bills, :action => :consumption_invoice
```

Idealy, I'd like to have both those rules in the `:me` namespace and the `:groups` resource blocks for making it cleaner to read. 
And I'd like to be able to add more actions easily:

```
/me/bills/subscription_invoice => :controller => :bills, :action => :subscription_invoice
```

which is why I wanted to create a block `:bills` in it.

I've been trying so many possibilities around, can't I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The way paths are constructed is different than the way the controller is determined.

Controllers can be organized under a namespace.  The namespace is a folder that controllers can sit in.  Although the order of resources and namespaces affects the order of the parts of the path, it won't affect the way that namespaces are treated as a controller grouping.  The resource is `:groups` so the controller is named "groups" and handles actions made against the group model.  The namespace is `:bills` so the controller is contained within a folder called "bills".

In a similar fashion, if you nested two resources like:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :users
end
```

The path for a user action would be /groups/:id/users but the controller would just be named "users".

If you really want this action to be handled by a bills controller in a groups folder, then you could customize the behavior with something like:

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    scope module: 'groups' do
      get 'bills/consumption_invoice', :format => :pdf, controller: 'bills'
    end
  end
end
```

**Additional Info for Edit in the Question**

If you just want your two paths to reach the `bills#consumption_invoice` action and you don't want your `bills` controller to live in a folder called `me`, you could consider something like this:

```
get 'me/bills/consumption_invoice', :format => :pdf, to: 'bills#consumption_invoice'

resources :groups do
  member do
    get 'bills/consumption_invoice', :format => :pdf, controller: 'bills'
  end
end
```

Rails will then expect that your `consumption_invoice` view lives in a `bills` folder.

The Rails Routing from the Outside In (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) can provide additional details on all the routing options.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm still confused though. I edited the question, could you maybe help me to get around this? Thanks

Comment: What will the `bills#consumption_invoice` action do?  If you arrive at this action from the path `/groups/:id/bills/consumption_invoice`, you will have a group id available, but if arrive there from the path `/me/bills/consumption_invoice` you will not have a group id.  What will the behavior be when the id is missing?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I know from where I come (little dirty I agree). But then I have `@consumer` which equals `Group.find(params[:id])` or `current_user` and the controller/view behave the same. Doesn't it make sense to do it this way? Cheers

Comment: That works.  Just wanted to make sure we didn't want to use the `collection` option instead of `member`.